# SQL create table or append

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm using PL/pgSQL and I'm trying to append some rows to a table, or if the table doesn't exist yet I want to create it and append the rows.
Is there some built-in syntax for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS name (definition)` before you INSERT data to it.

Comment: If I use this solution, then I must declare the columns of the table in the script (if I'll change one query I'll have to change the other), I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Thats correct.  And if the columns change, and the table is already there wtih different columns, then you are in trouble as well.

Comment: In this case, it's more logical to drop the table and start all over once I change the structure of the table.